# Can't load a specific webpage using Chrome or Safari while logged in, but they work on other account and Firefox also works

Tags: safari, google-chrome, firefox, ssl

I'm trying to access [The Guardian's website](https://www.theguardian.com/), and I get errors with both Safari and Chrome.

In Safari:

> **Safari Can't Open the Page**
>
> Safari can't open the page "https://www.theguardian.com" because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server "www.theguardian.com".

In Chrome:

> **Your connection is not private**
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from **theguardian.com** (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED

**EDIT**: The problem appears to have morphed somewhat in Safari, and I've found the same issue with [Kinja](https://www.kinja.com/). Now, instead of it refusing to load the page, it loads a page that looks like this:

[image]

Both sites appear to have certificates issued by GlobalSign Organization Validation CA, and both have the error "This certificate has an invalid issuer".

When I use Safari on my wife's user account or use Firefox on my own account, the website loads fine. How can I fix my browsers on my user account such that they also successfully load the website?

So far, I've unsuccessfully tried:

- In Safari, going to Preferences > Privacy, clicking 'Manage Website Data…' and deleting everything.
- Going into Keychain Access and resetting my login keychain to the default.
- Deleting the Safari-relevant folders in `~/Caches`.

Neither fixes the problem, but the problem is not present on other user accounts, so I don't think it can be a system-level issue.

Comment: Clear the caches/cookies from Chome and Safari?

Comment: No, I tried that – doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after an evening of poking at the situation and trying to work out what's going on, I eventually worked it out.

As it transpires, there was an issue with the CRL and OCSP caches on my account on my iMac – other users did not have the same problem as a result. These caches are not deleted by deleting anything from `~/Caches`, which is why the issue didn't resolve when I tried that.

The answer came from the [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65639), who pointed me to [a page on the GlobalSign website](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1353318-view-and-or-delete-crl-ocsp-cache). The solution is to open Command Prompt/Terminal and enter one of the following commands, then reboot.

#### Windows

```
certutil -urlcache * delete
```

#### OS X (pre-Sierra)

```
sudo rm /var/db/crls/*cache.db
```

#### macOS Sierra

```
sqlite3 ~/Library/Keychains/*/ocspcache.sqlite3 'DELETE FROM ocsp;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Typing *thisisunsafe* (not in the address bar, but just on the page) whitelists the url/cert.

I'm using this workaround on sites I know to be legit (server cluster nodes with names that are different than the VIP they serve.) Use with caution - there is a reason why Chrome treats self-signed certs with suspicion.