# "Safari can't establish a secure connection" and OmniFocus sync is broken

Tags: network, safari, keychain, certificate, ssl

## Symptoms

> macOS 10.14.6, Safari 13.1, all updates applied.

### Safari refuses to connect to some websites.

`Safari Can't Open the Page [...] because Safari can't establish a secure connection to the server [...]`

I can 'resolve' this issue (see below), but when it re-occurs the sites always seem to be the same sites. A sample, in case anyone can find a pattern:

- https://theage.com.au (our local newspaper, cert issued by COMODO CA)
- https://bum-man.com.au (my girlfriend's site, deployed on Netlify, cert is Let's Encrypt)
- https://apple.stackexchange.com (oh, the irony – also Let's Encrypt)

This issue only occurs in Safari. I can browse these sites in Firefox. I can ping these sites.

It's not a specific CA, because I can browse to other Let's Encrypt sites just fine.

#### Other weirdness I've just noticed as I type this cry for help

- The 'Bum Man' site is hosted at Netlify. The canonical URL is https://bumman2020.netlify.com. This works just fine.
- I thought to check Brave. Brave refuses to connect, error `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID`. But when I inspect the certificate, *it is valid*. WTF! This is for https://theage.com.au:

[image: Brave connection refused with certificate A-OK]

### OmniFocus won't synchronise

I'm using Omni's sync service at https://sync3.omnigroup.com. If I navigate there in Safari, guess what:

[image: Certificate error for sync3.omnigroup.com]

But I can get there just fine in Firefox. And, again, *this works sometimes*. It was working yesterday after a reboot and then it just stops working at some point.

OmniFocus' sync logs from the other evening indicate that a scheduled sync was successful at 4am then unsuccessful by 4:15am. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

### OmniFocus log output

The full log is in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jen729w/a8e43fac3d7a9f58ed731d7e74910c90) but the relevant parts seem to be:

```
*** Error: {
    code = "-1200";
    domain = NSURLErrorDomain;
    userInfo =     {
        NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey = 0;
        NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://sync3.omnigroup.com/jen729w/OmniFocus.ofocus/";
        NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "https://sync3.omnigroup.com/jen729w/OmniFocus.ofocus/";
        NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey =         (
            "<cert(0x7fd0c508d600) s: sync3.omnigroup.com i: Let's Encrypt Authority X3>",
            "<cert(0x7fd0c5354200) s: Let's Encrypt Authority X3 i: DST Root CA X3>"
        );
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.";
```

---

## What I've tried

A reboot seems to fix this for a while. Then it comes back.

I've deleted my Keychain (Keychain Access > Prefs > Reset My Default Keychains). That fixed it for a while, and now it's back.

### Deleting my CRL & OCSP caches

I tried the 'delete your OCSP cache' instructions [from this StackExchange question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268492/cant-load-a-specific-webpage-using-chrome-or-safari-while-logged-in-but-they-w) but they don't work – presumably the sqlite database has moved in 10.14.

If I try to `mdfind ocspcache` the only hit is a Backblaze log file. It tells me I'll find `ocspcache.sqlite3-shm` at `~/Library/Keychains/9FD2154C-...-789F/` but I do not.

### It isn't my wifi

The issue occurs if I tether my phone's connection.

---

## Other factors

I do run a medley of software which might interfere with my network. But I'm pretty sure this isn't network related – like I say, I can ping these servers just fine.

- Mullvad (VPN). I use their macOS software. It's currently disconnected.
- Tailscale (VPN). I've recently installed their macOS software, but this issue pre-dates that.
- Little Snitch (firewall). Again, it's been on there forever. I run Peter Lowe's blocklist. Disabling it has no effect.

As you might imagine, this is driving me up the wall. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

## Update: the next day, 27 hours after a reboot...

It's broken again. I just noticed OmniFocus won't sync. It worked at 13:49 and by 14:02 was broken. I was doing nothing significant during this time (I wasn't even using the machine).

```
App: OmniFocus 3.6.3 (v140.14.0)
Device: antimony.local (n9YYRdUsikA)

Apr 6, 2020 at 1:49 PM Scheduled (11.99s) // Successful sync
Apr 6, 2020 at 2:02 PM Scheduled (3.08s)
*** Error: {
    code = "-1200";
    ...etc.
```

Current behaviour for https://theage.com.au is weird. On this user account, I just see Safari's 'can't open the page' grey screen. On another user account Safari warns me that the certificate is no good:

[image: Safari certificate warning for theage.com.au]

But it was just fine an hour ago. What's changed?

---

## Update Wed 8th April

Stranger still: if I open a private window in Safari and browse to one of the broken sites, Safari warns me that "this connection is not private" and gives me the chance to "visit this website" as long as I authenticate to confirm that it is safe to do so.

When in a non-private window, I am not given this option. It's just a flat-out "can't establish a secure connection".

[image: Private window weirdness]
[image: Private window weirdness 2]

Comment: I've just tried this on 3 different browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari) and can't replicate the issue - everything works with no problem.  Try creating a new user to see if it's something in your user profile.

Comment: Will do, although I just rebooted so now I have to wait for it to re-occur...

Comment: Do you have any Profiles installed on your Mac? (Is there a Profiles panel in System Preferences?)

Comment: Yep, a bunch from my mail provider (Migadu). None that aren't email server settings, i.e. nothing routing my SSL traffic through an organisation's network.

Comment: Theory: something happens after 24h of uptime. Disproven: just monitored before/after the 24h ticked over. Issue not occurring. Will test with another user as soon as I notice that the issue has come back.

Comment: Happened again. Updated the post. :-(

Comment: When replying to a comment, use @user so we can see the response.  I just happened to revisit as I was scrolling through the unanswered questions and saw these.

Comment: Do you have any Safari extensions installed? If you do, which ones?

Comment: @jaume 1Blocker and 1Password. Both been there forever, just disabled them, issue persists. Remember, as per my notes above, this issue exhibits itself in OmniFocus and Brave as well. It's a macOS certificate issue, I'm sure. I just don't know how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Hi John, I agree, it's a global cert issue. It looks like macOS accepts the root certs, but the chain of trust is somewhat broken. For https://theage.com.au, the "COMODO RSA CA" root cert is valid, but the "COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA" intermediate cert is not. Could you download all certs by selecting the cert and dragging the icon to the Desktop, and then run this command in Terminal `security verify-cert -v -c ~/Desktop/nine.com.au.cer -c ~/Desktop/COMODO\ RSA\ Organization\ Validation\ Secure\ Server\ CA.cer  -r ~/Desktop/COMODO\ RSA\ Certification\ Authority.cer`?

Comment: @jaume Just rebooted, so this is currently working in the browser. I'll repeat the process when it fails again. Note the `-v` in your command caused an error and I removed it. Output: `$ security verify-cert -c nine.com.au.cer  -c COMODO\ RSA\ Organization\ Validation\ Secure\ Server\ CA.cer -r COMODO\ RSA\ Certification\ Authority.cer 
...certificate verification successful.`

Comment: @jaume It's been 24h and it's failed again, so I re-exported the certificates ... and same result. `Certificate verification successful.`

Comment: Oh this is ridiculous now. It failed. So I quit Safari. Switched to my other user account. Didn't do anything. Switched back to this account. Launched Safari. Works. FFS.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. So it seems `security` accepts the chain of trust, while Safari doesn't. Could you post the output of command `openssl x509 -inform der -text -in ~/Desktop/<certificate>` for all three certificates, that is "COMODO RSA CA",  "COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA" and nine.com.au.cer, just to be sure these are the correct certificates (I know, it's quite a lot of text)? The message '<certificate> certificate is not standards compliant' just says that the certificate doesn't comply with security requirements in macOS 10.14, but why?

Comment: I'm starting to think that the profiles from your mail provider may be the culprit. Do those profiles add any security requirements for certificates? The man page of `security` states that when using the `verify-cert` option `[the certificate] is evaluated according to standard SSL server policy; other certificates or policy options will be ignored in this case`, which would explain why `security` thinks the chain of trust is valid, while Safari, applying the profile settings, doesn't. I don't have any explanation for certificates working for some time and then breaking, though...

Comment: @jaume I gave up and rebuilt my Mac! Had been thinking about doing it for other reasons anyway so I just went ahead and did it. We'll never know...

Comment: Alright, I can't blame you for that. If you happen to experience the same problems after installing your mail provider profiles, I'd be interested in hearing back from you...

Comment: @jaume I have exactly the same issue on an old Catalina Macbook Pro, everything is fine after a reboot, but after closing the lid and waiting for some time, the issue appears (maybe there are some other triggers I just haven't nocied). Don't have any profiles (no such item in the System Preferences)

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Evgeny Not really, the OP ended up rebuilding his Mac (can't blame him for that) so we couldn't find out what the culprit was. I'd recommend that you post a new question explaining in detail the issue you're experiencing,. You can reference this post, if you wish.

Comment: @jaume Thanks. Yeah, saw about rebuilding, but that's exactly what I hope to avoid :) Will try a few more random tweaks from google and then maybe will create a new issue (though I thought that duplicates aren't allowed)

Comment: @Evgeny You are right about duplicates, but in general the original question must have an answer (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) which doesn't apply here.